# CSS: margin issues

Tags: php, html, css, layout

I'm trying to output multiple elements in a single class, but i'm having trouble separating the top of page from the actual elements.

I've tried separating each image with `div.element img:not(:nth-of-type(1)){` and `div.element img:nth-of-type(1){` that didn't work. How would I manipulate the space between the first element, but not the others?

```
<div class="element">
<a href="http://website.com" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://website.com"></a>
</div>

<div class="element">
<div id="Projecttitle" class="Projecttitle">Test Title</div>
</div>


<div class="element">
<div id="Projectdescription" class="Projectdescription">Test description</div>
</div>
<div class="element">
<a href="http://website.com" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://website.com"></a>
</div>

<div class="element">
<div id="Projecttitle" class="Projecttitle">Test Title</div>
</div>


<div class="element">
<div id="Projectdescription" class="Projectdescription">Test description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly, looking at the posted image in your question, I'm not convinced that the padding of the first image is any different than the other two; though it perhaps looks that way due to the volume of white-space above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.element:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

div.element {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Will the first-child padding override the padding-top of the div.element attribute though?

Comment: Yes, that's the point -- the more specific selector takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML doesn't make sense. If you keep elements that logically belong together, you get semantic code that's much easier to style, like so:

```
<div class="project">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="#" alt="image">
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        <h1>Test Title</h1>  
        <p>Test description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.image {
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;
}

.text {
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.project:first-child .image,
.project:first-child .text {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.project:last-child .image,
.project:last-child .text {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bygz6/7/)

That should get you started!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.element:nth-of-type(1) img {
  padding-top: /* some value */;
}
```

The `:nth-of-type()`, and similar, pseudo-classes act on elements in the context of their parent. In other words, it only evaluates direct siblings. Your individual `<img>` elements are *not* siblings of each other, because they have different parents.

Comment: That works great for the first one, but how would I select all the other img except the first one and still have IE be compatible with it? Keep in mind I have to be able to repeat the <div class="element"> infinite times depending on how many rows there are. I am populating these rows via MYSQLI and PHP.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. Unfortunately, my css knowledge is not elaborated enough any more to know the fallback rules/hacks in (certain versions of) IE for this particular issue. Sorry. Hopefully someone else can chime in.